# .so file is not loading, when running the app on the virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-virtual-device, spatialite

I used a physical machine to develop and try to load the .so file.  I put all .so file under the "app/libs" folder and add the code at `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

    }
```

The application  performed good. But when I used virtual device to develop instead, it can not load the `.so` file. Android Studio print the error :

`No implementation found for void jsqlite.Database.internal_init()`

at the code `new jsqlite.Database();` It is a method of spatialite.

I try to create a new folder "src/main/jniLibs" and put the .so file in it, but it doesn't work.
How to solve the problem?
And I also notice that the virtual devices has a inner file: "/data/data/xxxxx/lib", it has any effect?

Comment: With ABI does the virtual device use? Have you built all your native libraries for that ABI?

Comment: the virtual device is Nexus 10 API 30 , the CPU/ABI is x86, I had built the arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a , x86_64

Comment: Well, then you'll eiher have to build for x86 as well, or modify your AVD to use one of those other 3 ABIs instead.